# <function-style-cast> error: Cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::thread'

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallelize quicksort using `std::threads`, and I am receiving an error I am unfamiliar with since I just started multithreading.  The error is probably so simple, I keep skipping over it.  Can someone please shed some light on the problem. Here is the code and the only error that appears:

```
        #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream> //cout, endl
#include <cstdlib>  //srand
#include <algorithm>//copy, random_shuffle
#include <iterator> //ostream_iterator
#include "ratio.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "quicksort.h"
#include "sort_small_arrays.h"

template< typename T>
unsigned partition(T* a, unsigned begin, unsigned end) {
    unsigned i = begin, last = end - 1;
    T pivot = a[last];

    for (unsigned j = begin; j<last; ++j) {
        if (a[j]<pivot) {
            std::swap(a[j], a[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    std::swap(a[i], a[last]);
    return i;
}

/* iterative */
#define STACK
#define xVECTOR
#define xPRIORITY_QUEUE 

#include <utility> // std::pair

template <typename T>
using triple = typename std::pair< T*, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>;

template< typename T>
struct compare_triples {
    bool operator() (triple<T> const& op1, triple<T> const& op2) const {
        return op1.second.first > op2.second.first;
    }
};

#ifdef STACK
#include <stack>
template< typename T>
using Container = std::stack< triple<T>>;
#define PUSH push
#define TOP  top
#define POP  pop
#endif

#ifdef VECTOR
#include <vector>
template< typename T>
using Container = std::vector< triple<T>>;
#define PUSH push_back
#define TOP  back
#define POP  pop_back
#endif

#ifdef PRIORITY_QUEUE
#include <queue>
template< typename T>
using Container = std::priority_queue< triple<T>, std::vector<triple<T>>, compare_triples<T> >;
#define PUSH push
#define TOP  top
#define POP  pop
#endif

//Thread quicksorts a single range of elements and decrements thread counter at the end
template< typename T>
void threadsort_iterative_aux(Container<T> & ranges, int &currentThreads)
{
    triple<T> r = ranges.TOP();
    ranges.POP();

    T*       a = r.first;
    unsigned b = r.second.first;
    unsigned e = r.second.second;

    //base case
    if (e - b<6) {
        switch (e - b) {
        case 5: quicksort_base_5(a + b); break;
        case 4: quicksort_base_4(a + b); break;
        case 3: quicksort_base_3(a + b); break;
        case 2: quicksort_base_2(a + b); break;
        }
        continue;
    }

    unsigned q = partition(a, b, e);

    ranges.PUSH(std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(b, q)));
    ranges.PUSH(std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(q + 1, e)));
    --currentThreads;
}

template< typename T>
void quicksort(T* a, unsigned begin, unsigned end, int num_threads)
{
    //Number of threads currently running other than the main thread
    int currentThreads = 0;

    //Ranges of elements to sort
    Container<T> ranges;
    ranges.PUSH(std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(begin, end)));

    //Dynamic vector of threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    //Loops till all threads are done AND nothing left to sort
    while (!ranges.empty() || currentThreads != 0)
    {
        //Doesn't bother doing anything if the range is empty but other threads are still running
        if (!ranges.empty())
        {
            //If we can make more threads, make a thread and give it the top range to sort
            if (currentThreads < num_threads)
            {
                ++currentThreads;
                threads.push_back(std::thread(threadsort_iterative_aux, std::ref(ranges), std::ref(currentThreads)));

            }
            //Starts sorting itself if maximum number of threads are running
            else
            {
                triple<T> r = ranges.TOP();
                ranges.POP();
                T*       a = r.first;
                unsigned b = r.second.first;
                unsigned e = r.second.second;

                //Optimized sorting of a range between 2 and 5 elements
                if (e - b < 6) {
                    switch (e - b) {
                    case 5: quicksort_base_5(a + b); break;
                    case 4: quicksort_base_4(a + b); break;
                    case 3: quicksort_base_3(a + b); break;
                    case 2: quicksort_base_2(a + b); break;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                unsigned q = partition(a, b, e);

                ranges.PUSH(std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(b, q)));
                ranges.PUSH(std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(q + 1, e)));
            }
        }
    }
}

template< typename T>
bool check_is_sorted(T* a, unsigned size)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i<size; ++i) {
        if (!(a[i - 1] <= a[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool test_int(unsigned size, unsigned num_threads) {
    int* a = new int[size];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i<size; ++i) { a[i] = i; }
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(NULL)));
    std::random_shuffle(a, a + size);
    quicksort(a, 0, size, num_threads);
    bool retval = check_is_sorted(a, size);
    delete[] a;
    return retval;
}

void test0() {
    if (test_int(200, 1)) { std::cout << "OK\n"; }
    else { std::cout << "Failed\n"; }
}

#include <cstdio>    /* sscanf */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    test0();
    return 0;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2440   '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::thread' Line 145 (contains:

threads.push_back(std::thread(threadsort_iterative_aux, std::ref(ranges), std::ref(currentThreads)));)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a `triple<T>` as the first parameter to `threadsort_iterative_aux` when creating the thread, but the function expects a `Container<T> &` there.

Also note that passing parameters by non-const-reference with this signature, you need to wrap the parameters in `std::ref()` at the caller's side.

This is basically the same behavior as with `std::bind`: If you omit the `std::ref`, the compiler will copy the value into the binding and then pass that copy as a parameter into the function call upon invocation. Since the copy is immutable though, that will break with non-const references. Which is a good thing, as it protects you from accidentally losing the side-effects on that parameter.

Last but not least, the bind mechanism breaks template-argument deduction. Since you are not actually calling the function at the point where you create the thread, the compiler is unable to deduce the template parameter for the function from the arguments automatically. You have to give the parameter explicitly:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(threadsort_iterative_aux<T>, std::ref(ranges), std::ref(currentThreads)));
//                               note the <T> here  ---^
```

Since these are a mighty bunch of bind-headaches to worry about, you might want to just use a lambda instead, which suffers from none of those issues:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { threadsort_iterative_aux(ranges, currentThreads); }));
```

Comment: Hmmm, I thought your input would fix the error.
I changed the line to the following:
    threads.push_back(std::thread(threadsort_iterative_aux, std::ref(ranges), std::ref(currentThreads)));

But the same error persists.  Did I do it incorrectly?  Or did you catch a bug that I would have had to deal with after fixing the error?

Comment: @AmrotheStudent That line looks correct now. Unfortunately, the code you posted is incomplete, which makes it hard to diagnose the error further. Can you edit the post to show [a complete, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also include the full error message that you get from the compiler?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how much to show you so I took out what I thought would be irrelevant.  I left the drivers and main function, you should be able to copy-paste and run to see the same error now.  I will edit the code back down if it is still too much.

Comment: Ok, I made it shorter and more "minimal."

Comment: @AmrotheStudent I edited the answer. There seem to be some minor unrelated problems with the sample code you posted, but I think you will be able to figure those out on your own :)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how I would've figured that out on my own.  Is there a reference that you used to help deduce the answer?

Comment: @AmrotheStudent It's mostly experience from using `boost::bind` before we had lambdas in the language. The best advice that I can give for handling these is try to understand what the functions do under the hood. If you have a rough idea how bind is implemented, using it correctly becomes a lot easier. The [docs for boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) are a good read. Also the [docs on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) are invaluable once you learn to decipher their technical wording.